# Can't grant myself permissions to execute `rm` command as sudo

Tags: permissions, sudo, visudo

I have a user account on my machine:

```
$ (whoami)
> foo_user
```

I've updated by `/etc/sudoers` file to grant myself permissions to use the `rm` command:

```
User_Alias      OPERATORS = foo_user
Cmnd_Alias      RM = /bin/rm
OPERATORS       ALL = RM
OPERATORS       ]ALL = (ALL) ALL
```

However, when I try to run rm on a directory, I get a permissions denied error:

```
rm: /root-directory: Permission denied
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Putting your userid in the `sudoers` file allows you to preface your command with `sudo` (e.g. `sudo rm /root-directory`). It does not grant constant `root`-ness. One does NOT always want to be `root`.

Read `man sudo`